# Best model for learning function with shape 1/x^2?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

What model/estimator would you guys use to learn data which has the shape like 1/x^2 ?
Example :

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx^2%2C+from+0+to+1
```

The best behaved from what I tested up to now is Support Vector Regression (SVR)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: What is a good estimator (SVR,LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge,....etc) to model data that looks like 1/x^2 i.e. inverted slope....smaller-X, bigger y

Comment: least square?  if you can already parameterize it, then just use least square.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question: if you know it looks like `1 / x^2`, then use `1 / x^2`.

Support Vector Machines are likely to work well or even best in a lot of problems.

Since your data is obviously not generated by a linear process, I suggest you don't use any linear estimator. Other than that, a lot of estimators can work well. Pick one and see if you're happy with it.